# Transversality in the Zariski tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I am trying to understand how to check whether two algebraic varieties intersect transversally from a purely algebraic standpoint. Is the following argument correct?

Say locally a smooth projective variety $X$ is modeled by Spec $R$ with subvarieties $A$ = Spec $R/I$ and $B$ = Spec $R/J$. Then there is a map $\Phi: R \mapsto R/I \oplus R/J$ ($f \mapsto \phi_1(f) \oplus \phi_2(f)$ where $\phi_i$ are the quotient maps). If $\mathfrak{m}_{X,p}$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $R_p$ and similarly for $\mathfrak{m}_{A,p}$, $\mathfrak{m}_{B,p}$, then $\Phi$ descends to a map $\Psi$ of Zariski cotangent spaces $$\mathfrak{m}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_{X,p}^2 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}_{A,p}/\mathfrak{m}_{A,p}^2 \oplus \mathfrak{m}_{B,p}/\mathfrak{m}_{B,p}^2.$$Then $A$ and $B$ of complementary codimension intersect transversally at $p$ in their intersection if the map if and only if $\Psi$ is injective (so its dual is surjective).

Is this correct? If not, can somebody point me in the direction of the correct argument? I have looked in both Vakil and Hartshorne to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean by that sentence "a projective variety $X$ is modeled by Spec $R$" in terms of the language in Hartshorne's book?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just mean it is locally isomorphic to (Spec $R$,$\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec }R}$).

Comment: Not at all. But I don’t know what it means by a projective variety to be locally isomorphic to an affine variety. Did you mean to say $A$ is an affine open cover of $X$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that Spec $R$ is part of an open affine cover of $X$ (containing $p$.)

Comment: I don't know which direction you are asking as in your post it is mixed up. But $\Psi$ injective is not enough (but I think isomorphism would be). Take $R = k[x,y,z]$ and $m = (x,y,z)$ and $I = (x,y), J = (y,z)$. Then $\Psi$ is injective, but $I$ and $J$ do not define subvarieties of complentary codimention.

Comment: I don't think this $\Psi$ is injective - $y$ should map to $0$ in both cotangent spaces.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. $I, J$ need to be $I= (x)$ and $J= (z)$ instead. Can you check this example?

Comment: In this case the two subvarieties do meet transversally in the sense that their tangent spaces together span the tangent space of $\mathbb{A}^2$, so $\Psi$ should be injective. This is not a test of whether the subvarieties intersect in the correct dimension but whether they meet transversally.

Comment: That's fine. But can you edit your post so your assumption and question can be separated clearly? This is the statement I'm referring to is that "Then A and B of complementary codimension intersect transversally at  in their intersection if the map if and only if Ψ is injective (so its dual is surjective)."

Comment: Also, can you define your definition of two subschemes intersecting transversally?